# Can we call badges "achievements"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, site-attributes, badges

Given the theme of this StackExchange site, would it be possible to change the "badge" labels on the site to read "achievement"? Badges *were* [inspired](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/) by the Xbox 360, after all. :-)

Comment: though I wouldnt mind, i bet there would be upset people because they were not called trophies or something like that...

Comment: Steam, Plus+ and Xbox Live all call them achievements.  Seems to be heading in that direction.  Though I see no reason to actually change the name of badges.

Comment: I fear the SO-team doesn't want to customize each and every site...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it is true that badges were inspired directly by Xbox 360 Achievements, I think we'd prefer to keep most of the core "experience" elements the same across all the family for consistency.