# Does anyone else think they should change 'reputation' to 'exp'?

Tags: discussion

Then earning badges could be like proficiencies or something.

Plus they could make other stackexchange sites more customizable if it was possible to do all this in the database.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343/would-a-level-bar-or-other-gaming-mods-be-of-interest-for-the-gaming-se

Comment: First wait till the site comes out of Beta, then judge again :)

Comment: Whew, you aren't Evan Carroll :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the same reasons for officially turning down [the proposal to rename badges "achievements"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/can-we-call-badges-achivements) will apply here. To quote Jeff Atwood's answer on that question:

> [...] I think we'd prefer to keep most of the core "experience" elements the same across all the family for consistency.

As [Oak's link shows](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/would-a-level-bar-or-other-gaming-mods-be-of-interest-for-the-gaming-se), there are options for people to create customizations that individual users may choose to apply. I believe that would be a better avenue to approach than to alter the core system and experience for all users.